# TDD in a rest api

Tags: c#, tdd, servicestack

I am developing a Rest api with ServiceStack. I'm doing a tdd aproach, and write tests with each new service I implement.

My DAL is pretty thin, with my repositories consisting of only crud operations. Moreover, the repos inherit from a C# generics repository, with 12 out of my 14 not needing any customization.

For each service I build a test bed, and go through all the possible error/success scenarios that can ocurr.

Is it correct in this scenario to only produce tests for repositories? In what situations should I consider testing other system components?

Thanks

Comment: FYI the [Testing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Testing) shows different ways of testing the Data layer in ServiceStack.

Answer (score 3):

TTD involves using many tests to keep you code clean and functional. It sound to me that so far you have implemented *unit tests*. Unit tests are tests that only look at a single class and attempt to determine if the class is working correctly. Nothing more, nothing less.

If you want to test a little more broadly, you can implement *integration tests*. Integration tests tend to test a full system to see if *everything together* is capable of doing what it is supposed to.

Unit test are all supposed to be very fast, so that you can run them all every few minutes without much slowdown.

Integration tests are allowed to take longer, because you might only run them every few hours to see if everything is still integrating well.

A combination of both types of tests help drive a TTD approach.

Comment: +1 @Blitzkrieg I'd also add that of the two types, the integration tests are more important. One of TDD's strengths is that it focuses coding effort on delivering functionality. This has the benefit of helping to prevent overly complex code. Integration tests are how this is accomplished. Unit tests, which almost always test methods, are more focused on fine grained input/output, edge cases, and exception throwing/handling. It is easy to get lost in the weeds in TDD unit tests. I normally don't even bother to write TDD unit tests. Those get written after the code.

Comment: @KeithPayne Considering that, I don't call my methods directly (i use a JsonServiceClient), will those still be integration tests? I mean, there is no deploy as I use a self hosted AppHost (not on iis) and in memory database.

Comment: @Blitzkrieg Yes, those are integration tests. Unit testing is done by intentionally isolating each unit (class) by substituting mock ups for all of the class's immediate dependencies. When the dependencies are not mocked up, it is integration testing.